# Uploading image with a form in meteor on form submit

Tags: forms, meteor

I'm trying to create a simple web app that will ask the user to fill out a few questions and then upload a photo. I'd like for all of this information to be stored in a Meteor collection when the submit button is pressed, but I'm having some difficulty with the FS Collection package.

Here is the relevant main.html:

```
    <form class="photoForm">
    Problem: <input type = "text" id = "problem" placeholder="page # problem #"><br><br>
    Your group members <input type = "text" id="group" size="50"> <br><br>
    Your questions and comments about this problem: <br><br>
    <textarea name="comments" form="photo" rows="4" cols="70" placeholder="Enter text here..."></textarea>
    <br>

    Upload a snapshot of your work here: <input type = "file" id = "myFileInput">
    <br /><br />

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

Here's the main.js:

```
Template.form.events({ 
'click input[type=submit]': function(event, template) {

console.log("form submit")
event.preventDefault();

FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {


  Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj){
    //Inserted new doc with ID fileObj._id, and kicked off the data upload using HTTP
  });

});
 }   
});
```

Here are my questions:

1. I can only get the file to upload on the event 'change .myFileInput'. I've tried to get it to upload on 'click input[type=submit]' and 'submit' and it doesn't upload the file. Is there a way to get it to upload the file when the submit button is clicked?
2. How do I add data from the various text fields to the image collection? Can I incorporate these additions into the Images.insert() command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the autoform package

[autoform package](https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/autoform)

And the cfs autoform package
[Cfs autoform](https://atmospherejs.com/cfs/autoform)

These packages are very helpful

Comment: Yes, I was able to get it working with cfs:autoform.